# Edit the shortcut that closes Atom

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, vim-plugin

I have `vim` and `vim nerd tree` and many more packages installed on atom (`Linux`), the problem is that when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, the Atom IDE is closed instead of the focused file, how can I find out the plugin that added this shortcut? or how to disable it ?

Comment: Did you try ctrl+w ?

Comment: yes,  it's used by vim-nerd-tree plugin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to find out the plugin that added this shortcut?

Get to the keybinding tab in the Settings view (`File -> Settings -> Keybindings`) and type `ctrl-q` into the search bar.

[image: Keybindings in Atom]